# Which is the proper way to install postgresql [14.04]

Tags: 14.04, server, software-installation, postgresql

Recently I have been trying to install a postgres server instance on 14.04 but I've run into the issue of not knowing which install I need/want.

here are the different ones I've found

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL#Installation
- `sudo apt-get install postgres-xc`
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/install-short.html

What I am trying to implement is just a non distributed database that can be remotely accessed. My initial attempts where with the first link but it did not include the 'initdb' command and suggested I install postgres-xc which in turn broke my first installation.

Any explanation on the different installations of postgres would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the Ubuntu packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL#Installation), or if you want a newer PostgreSQL than is available in your Ubuntu release, install from the packages provided at http://apt.postgresql.org/ .

You do not need to install from source code per install-short.html if there are packages for your operating system.

Postgres-XC is a different product, based on PostgreSQL. You do not need it unless you plan on using a distributed DB. Why are you considering that as an option?

Comment: postgres-xc is the suggested product when I tried to use the 'initdb' method, so I installed it mostly out of curiosity.